# CakePHP 3 Paginator and URL parameters

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I'm displaying a bunch of database query results using the Paginator in a table in my view. I have a few pages of results. I've also added the ability to sort this data using `this->Paginator->sort()`, which also works fine.

The only issue is that if I go to the next page (eg page 2 from page 1), all the selected sort options are stripped from the URL. How can I tell the paginator to remember sort options between pages?

Comment: Use get method and pass those requests with your pagination too.

Comment: I guess you are talking about [this](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7324) issue.

Comment: @Cellydy : how are your current sorting option working? is the `param` pass in url ?

Comment: @urfusion I figured it out, posted below. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. In my view I had to parse the sort parameters:

`$this->Paginator->options(['url' => ['sort' => $this->request->query('sort'),'direction' => $this->request->query('direction')]]);`

Thanks @urfusion for the tip!